# How to use Pandas DataFrame.applyMap method

Tags: python, pandas

```
            AES  AIG    AIV
1/3/2008          1 
2/6/2008      1     
2/11/2008     1   1


!cat dd.csv
,AES,AIG,AIV
1/3/2008 16:00,,1,
2/6/2008 16:00,1,,
2/11/2008 16:00,1,,1

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s_input_file = 'dd1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(s_input_file, sep=',',header=0) #orders.csv

def getcell(x):
    if (x==1.0 and df.ix[x, df.ix[x]==1.0].values[0]==1.0):
        print x, df.ix[x, df.ix[x]==1.0].index[0], df.ix[x][0]

df.applymap(getcell)
```

Got correct 4 counts of output but not referring to right index row and col
"How to print the row index and column where cell == 1?"

```
1.0 AES 2/6/2008 16:00
1.0 AES 2/6/2008 16:00
1.0 AES 2/6/2008 16:00
1.0 AES 2/6/2008 16:00
```

How can I get the expected output like so:

```
   1/3/2008, AIG
   2/6/2008, AES
   2/11/2008, AES
   2/11/2008, AIG
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. In particular, the output you put at the end doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: Added expected output

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to strip out the whitespace in this example?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do with `applymap` won't work because the parameter is the value of the cell that is passed in, you have no knowledge from which row or column the value is from hence your code just prints the same value four times.

What you want to do is iterate over each row and column, test the value for `NaN` and print the index value and column name

```
for index in df.index:
    for col in df.columns:
        if notnull(df.loc[index,col]):
            print index, col

# outputs

1/3/2008 16:00 AIG
2/6/2008 16:00 AES
2/11/2008 16:00 AES
2/11/2008 16:00 AIV
```

Also just to critique your code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(s_input_file, sep=',',header=0) #orders.csv
# the above can be changed to the more compact
df = pd.read_csv(s_input_file) # sep and header have default values that will work for you

def getcell(x):
    if (x==1.0 and df.ix[x, df.ix[x]==1.0].values[0]==1.0):
                       ^ well this does not do what you think
```

You are trying to index using `.ix` but what you get is the value of the cell so it will be `NaN` or `1.0` so it is wrong, you should use `.loc` for label indexing or `.iloc` for integer based indexing. Also I am not sure why you perform a value comparison using `df.ix[x]==1.0]` and then call `.values[0]=1.0`??

```
        print x, df.ix[x, df.ix[x]==1.0].index[0], df.ix[x][0]
```

With the above code again the incorrect assumption of what `.ix` is doing being made here and you just print the same line everytime.